# В клавиатуру чат бота вк, написанного на PHP, не удается встроить кнопку ссылку

Tags: php, вконтакте

Господа, добрый вечер. Вопрос следующий. Сталкивался ли кто нибудь с разработкой ботов вк с клавиатурой на языке PHP с помощью callback API? Дело в том, что есть необходимость вставить кнопку - ссылку, однако при ее вставке (вот код кнопки, который добавляется к остальным кнопкам (обычным) в массив, который потом отправляется вместе с ответом бота

```
[ 
'action' => [ 
'type' => "open_link", 
'link' => 'example.com', 
"payload" => json_encode('8', JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), 
'label' => 'Text', 
], 
'color' => 'default' 
];
```

притом, формат ссылки пробовал вставлять, как с http так и без)
Однако при таком добавлении кнопки в массив с остальными кнопками (обычными), бот зависает и не выводит всю клавиатуру
При этом без этой кнопки - все выводится корректно. Лог неудавшихся запросов к серверу тоже молчит. Быть может нужно как то дополнительно кодировать ссылку(пробовал кодировать функцией urlencode()) или иначе строить логику кнопки? Не нашел в документации такого случая, сможете подсказать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример функции:

```
class message_send_keyboard{  
    public function send($msg, $keyboard, $user_id, $access_token){ 
        $request_params = array(
            "user_id" => $user_id,
            "random_id" => "0",
            "message" => $msg,
            "keyboard" => json_encode($keyboard, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),
            "access_token" => $access_token,
            "v" => "5.103");
        $get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
        file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?".$get_params);}}
```

Ответ на ваш вопрос:

```
$key_general = [
                    "one_time" => false,
                    "buttons" => [
                [
                    ["action" => [
                    "type" => "open_link",
                    "link" => "example.com",
                    "label" => "Your URL",
                    "payload" => '{"button": "1"}'],
                    "color" => "primary"]
                ]]];
```

Выполнение:

```
$ms = new message_send_keyboard;
$ms->send("Hello World", $key_general, $user_id, $access_token);
```